# htaccess and redirects

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm wanting my URL to resolve to `https://example.com` if the visitor is typing in the URL with `http://www` or `http://` or `https://www`

Right now I have a redirect in my htaccess and it works but I get warnings in sites like ahrefs that I shouldn't have 301s.

Here's my `.htaccess` file

Any help is appreciated

```
# Turn on Rewrite Engine
RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^bluehonudesign\.com$
# RewriteRule ^ https://bluehonudesign\.com [R=301,L]

# RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
# RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteOptions inherit

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # Set the Content-Security-Policy header to allow frames and form actions from Google and Facebook
    
    # Replace '<ALLOWED_DOMAINS>' above with the URLs of domains you want to allow connections to
    
    # Rest of your existing header configurations
    Header set X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"
    Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
    Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
    Header set X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies "none"
    Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload"
    Header set Referrer-Policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade"

    # Set the Permissions-Policy header to control various features and APIs
    # Customize the values as needed based on your website's requirements
    <FilesMatch "\.(html|php)$">
        Header set Feature-Policy "camera 'none'; fullscreen 'self'; geolocation *; microphone 'self' https://www.google/* https://www.facebook/*"
        Header set Permissions-Policy "camera=(), microphone=(), geolocation=(), fullscreen=(self)"
    </FilesMatch>

    # Enable headers module
    Header append Cache-Control "public"
    Header set Pragma "public"
    Header unset ETag

    # Cache rules for different file types
    # 30 days is 2592000
    # 31536000 is 1 year
    <FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|xml|txt|json)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "public, max-age=60"
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\.(css|js)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "public, max-age=60" 
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\.(ico|svg|png|gif|jpg|jpeg|bmp)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "public, max-age=60" 
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\.(ogg|mp4|webm)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "public, max-age=31536000"
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\.(woff|woff2|ttf|otf|eot)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "public, max-age=31536000"
    </FilesMatch>

    # Check if browser supports WebP images
    # Check if WebP replacement image exists
    # Serve WebP image instead
    <FilesMatch "\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$">
        Header append Vary Accept env=REQUEST_image
        Header set Content-Type "image/webp" env=REQUEST_image
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

# If your server doesn't support ETags deactivate with "None" (and remove header)
<IfModule mod_expires.c> 
    <IfModule mod_headers.c> 
        Header unset ETag 
    </IfModule> 
    FileETag None 
</IfModule>

# 301 REDIRECT HTTP TO HTTPS AND WWW TO NON-WWW
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

    # Check if browser supports WebP images
    # Check if WebP replacement image exists
    # Serve WebP image instead
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/webp
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.webp -f
    RewriteRule (.+)\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ $1.webp [T=image/webp,E=REQUEST_image]

    # Add trailing slash to target URLs
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
    RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
</IfModule>

# Backup Migration START
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteRule .* - [E=noconntimeout:1,E=noabort:1]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_env>
    SetEnv noabort 1
</IfModule>
# Backup Migration END

# Permanent redirects for pages no longer available

RedirectMatch 301 http://bluehonudesign.com/ https://bluehonudesign.com/index.php
RedirectMatch 301 http://www.bluehonudesign.com/ https://bluehonudesign.com/index.php
RedirectMatch 301 https://www.bluehonudesign.com/ https://bluehonudesign.com/index.php

ErrorDocument 400 /400.shtml 
ErrorDocument 401 /401.shtml 
ErrorDocument 402 /402.shtml 
ErrorDocument 403 /403.shtml 
ErrorDocument 404 /404.shtml 
ErrorDocument 405 /405.shtml 
ErrorDocument 410 /410.shtml 
ErrorDocument 429 /429.shtml 
ErrorDocument 500 /500.shtml
ErrorDocument 501 /501.shtml
ErrorDocument 502 /502.shtml 
ErrorDocument 503 /503.shtml 
ErrorDocument 504 /504.shtml 

# Set the “ea-php81” package as the default “PHP” programming
<IfModule mod_php8.c>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php81
</IfModule>

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php74” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php74___lsphp .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Comment: "I get warnings in sites like ahrefs that I shouldn't have 301s." - What exactly is the "warning" you are seeing? Are you linking to (and submitting) the canonical URL only throughout your site? `RewriteOptions inherit` - What directives are you "inheriting"? You have repeated the same rule twice in your config (not the cause of an error) and the `RedirectMatch` directives are not doing anything and should be removed.

Comment: It would seem your domain is covered by HSTS (the HSTS header is sent from Nginx, not Apache) and the www to non-www redirect appears to be handled by an Nginx server (not Apache). So, at least with regards to "redirects", it doesn't appear your Apache server is doing anything?! The "sites like ahrefs" might be "confused" by the HSTS, since a request for `http://www.example.com` would need to be redirected to `https://www.example.com` (same host) before redirecting to `https://example.com` (2 redirects). But this is not a problem (it is a requirement of HSTS).

Comment: So my script that I'm using is incorrect? Do you have a suggestion on where to go to generate or fund a proper script?

Comment: I say apache because there's an .htaccess file in my shared hosting public html directory.

Comment: "I'm wanting my URL to resolve to https://example.com" - why? This closes the door on high availability for your website.

Comment: @symcbean - High availability, where? In what way? If a user enters http://www.example.com and the script rewrites the URL as https://example.com doesn't that eliminate "availability"?

Also - canonical can only be placed once in the <head> of a page. There could be 4 different canonicals 

http://www.example.com/
http://example.com/
https://www.example.com/
https://example.com

You have to pick one, or you're going to get non-canonical errors. Shouldn't htaccess be used to prevent this error from happening so there's only one URL formed and read by the search engines?

Comment: Rewrites have got nothing to do with HA. DNS does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning you're getting from Ahrefs is not about the existence of 301 redirects on your website. It is saying you're still linking to the old URLs and allowing the 301 to provide correct UX.

You're being advised to update the links to those old URLs so that SEO value of them is being passed to the correct URLs without the possible complication of a 301 in the way.

You need to make sure when you move URLs that any sitemaps, internal navigation, links within content, or canonical URLs are properly updated, as well as implementing 301 redirects from the old URLs to the new.

Comment: I'm not referring to http://* or https://www in any of my onsite links or sitemap

Comment: Well, that's fine. How about internal or external links to incorrect URL formats? It's been a long while since I used Ahrefs (my agency uses SEMRush), but do you define which URLs it scans or does it hold a cache of your site's structure from before you implemented the 301s?

Comment: You give it the URL and it scans the site.

Comment: What I'm getting in ahrefs is 301 Moved permanently
http://bluehonudesign.com/ 
0
301
https://bluehonudesign.com/ 
200
No
0 0  
37
HTML
301 Moved permanently
https://www.bluehonudesign.com/ 
301
https://bluehonudesign.com/ 
200

HTML
301 Moved permanently
http://www.bluehonudesign.com/

Comment: @ChrisJ.Popp You need to add that information to your question and correctly formatted (as _code_ in order to show the complete URL). Including the HTTP response headers for such a redirect would also be useful... since, having had a quick look at your site, it would seem the redirect response is coming from an Nginx server, not Apache?! (You may be behind a front-end proxy that is handling these non-canonical requests.)

Comment: I'm on an apache server. Have confirmed with my host provider that it indeed is an Apache server. 

Original question has been formatted so the htaccess info is displayed in code format. 

I've figured out the ahrefs issue that I was having was a combination of removing /index.php from the url in the canonical and sitemap.